# Make requests through a static IP in Heroku with Fixie (or other)?

Tags: heroku, networking, request, static-ip-address

I need to make requests through the static IP that Fixie(or other) sets for Heroku.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. We currently use [Quotaguard](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardstatic) for this. But be aware that this solutions can become expensive if you're making a lot of requests.

Also you need to have access to the SSL certificate + secret if you want to setup SSL/HTTPS.